# if (S == 0) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed}, raster::calc

Tags: r, stack, raster

I have a raster stack of 70 layers (same months in 70 years in a row) and trying to find the trend (with pre-whitening).

Since pwmk is only applied to vectors, I wrote a function below (tsfun) to apply "pwmk" to my rasterstack and extracting sen's slope.

```
tsfun = function(st,na.rm=TRUE){
if(all(is.na(st))){return(NaN)}
return(pwmk(st)[["Sen's Slope"]])
}
```

Then I used raster::calc as below to calculate the sen's slope

```
sen.slop <- raster::calc(st,tsfun)
```

I have multiple time series (different months of all 70 years) and already applied the process to all of them. I only have issues with 3 months of one single variables, for which I receive the following error.

```
Error in if (S == 0) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed}
```

Any help or suggestions will be definitely helpful and appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one condition that leads to this error.

```
library(modifiedmk)
pwmk(rep(0, 3))[["Sen's Slope"]]
# Error in if (S == 0) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

So you need to catch these cases in `tsfun`. Perhaps do something along these lines:

```
tsfun = function(st,na.rm=TRUE){
   if(all(is.na(st))){return(NaN)}
   if(length(unique(st)) == 1){return(0)}
   return(pwmk(st)[["Sen's Slope"]])
}
```

Try it

```
tsfun(rep(10,3))
#[1] 0
```